# dotnet run command in my asp.net failed without error

Tags: c#, .net, web

I was running ok untill today.
I tried to run `dotnet run` or `dotnet watch` in the project directory but the run failed without displaying any errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDUZK.png)

Comment: Can you run `dotnet build` to see if it will give you any error output or not?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured the problem , it was a syntax error. I , by mistake,removed the line of run() in program.cs.